# Unable to resolve dependency using transform JetifyTransform?

Tags: android, android-jetpack

## Unable to resolve dependency using transform JetifyTransform ?

#### Error:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Failed to 
transform file 'billing-1.0.aar' to match attributes {artifactType=jetified- 
aar} using transform JetifyTransform
```

Comment: I'm getting this now too after trying to update to the new androidx support packages. I think. Did you get past this yet?

Comment: I do not know about the correct answer but for temporary solution, Try android.enableJetifier=false in gradle.properties

Comment: Have done so. Though, since I'm using AndroidInjectors with Dagger 2, this causes other problems. I guess we should just wait until the tools are stable, because right now, they aren't.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Happy coding!

Comment: Upgrade your fabric version to '1.25.4', This will solve your problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hello Guys, I found the solution.**

What you need to do is to upgrade your Firebase crashlytics fabric version to `1.25.4` in your project `build.gradle` file:

```
    ...

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4' // Crashlytics
        ...
    }

    ...
```

Also, you should make sure you're not using an older version of Android KTX (like version 0.3).